# Is it possible to bind <esc> to kill-whole-line in cshell?

Tags: linux, csh

Due to using Matlab and ipython, I have muscle memory to hit escape to blow away a line and start over. Is it possible to make a key binding to kill-whole-line for the escape key? I don't really understand what I'm doing, but have tried things like this:

```
bindkey -k escape kill-whole-line
```

but that doesn't actually work.

Comment: kill->clear. Kill usually means to kill a running process in shell-speak

Comment: kill-whole-line does what I want, it is just bound to ctrl-U by default in my setup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes:

```
bindkey '^[' kill-whole-line
```

However, since Escape is also used as a prefix for arrow keys and Meta combos, you may be better off using e.g. two escapes so as not to interfere with them:

```
bindkey '^[^[' kill-whole-line
```